# Build process in web development?

Tags: node.js, build

I used to be a freelance web developer many many moons ago, and I've recently started updating my skillset in the last few months. Back in the day, if I was creating a web page for a small business in my town, I'd just write some HTML, CSS, and PHP, put it up on a server, and boom they had a site.

Now, while I understand that's still possible, I want to learn the better way. I'm focusing on the MEVN stack, and I see build systems mentioned all over the place. "Production builds will be put in ./dist," etc.

Can someone explain how this all flows? What do I get out of building my app that I don't get out of just dropping the file structure in place on a server? Where's the best place to start learning the best-practice build tools out there?

I know this is a VERY broad question, so I don't expect everything could be covered, but even a general understanding of the "why" and the "how" would be helpful.

Comment: Awesome question imo. Was looking for such a resource as well when i started learning this stuff! Might create a detailed answer tomorrow since i think many people are struggeling on this!

Comment: thanks @jdickel. If you get a chance, I'd love to hear your thoughts.

Comment: Sure, you‘re welcome. I try to make some time for this :)

Comment: *What do I get out of building my app that I don't get out of just dropping the file structure in place on a server?* - you won't be able to run it without building, simple as that. Can this be considered a valuable outcome for build step? You can't load SASS/SCSS styles in a browser without building them to CSS. You can't run Vue source files in a browser without building them to plain JS, preferably ES5.

Comment: @estus why wont' I be able to run it without building? That's part of what I don't understand. I get that SASS/SCSS has to be compiled, but what if I just wrote regular CSS?

Comment: For plain JS, you can choose obsolete frameworks like AngularJS or Vue 1. React is awful without JSX but is fully functional, too. They don't have problems with being used like that, although not every third-party library you may be interested in supports this workflow.

Comment: Modern JS features have poor support in browsers. You don't want a website that works for 70% users. Some of the features that are very demanded in JS development aren't supported by browsers at all, this means 0% users. You could restrict yourself from using them, thus seriously limiting your toolset. But since you're targeting Vue 2 as a part of MEVN, you need to know that it it isn't fully functional without build step. https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/ is intended to be used with Webpack. You will have hard time writing plain ES5 that needs no compiling and bundling with modern frameworks.

Comment: Why would you write plain CSS? SCSS exists for a good reason, it makes style development much more efficient. So do JS flavours that require compilation. That's the point. Tools were invented to bring it to another level. *HTML, CSS, and PHP, put it up on a server, and boom they had a site* - this is considered the stone age. Nobody wants to return there. There was no wheel and no FB. These days you run `npm run deploy`, the machine gathers the things up, runs all automated tests and uploads it to your server with zero human mistakes. Hope the metaphor helps.